# IllegalThreadExeption for running thread in surfaceView, specific to Lunar Lander example

Tags: java, android, multithreading

So I have an app that uses a surface view that runs a separate thread for the UI. It was taken almost directly from the Lunar Landing sample app. The app also uses Bluetooth service on another thread but I am sure that this is not related to the problem because I can disable bluetooth all together and it still happens.

The problem in my app is that the app when closed and then reopened does not start running the UI thread after`thread.start()` except it throws an error. In the Lunar example they have `thread.start()` in the onSurfaceCreated method. The problem is when I restart my app (it calls onPause then onSurfaceDestroy) the thread is already running and I get an error when I try to start it. My code for onSurfaceCreated, onPause, onResume and onSurfaceDestroyed is all the same as the example. I know I can use `if (this.getState() == Thread.State.NEW) {` but that seems like it will mask some of my other issues. I want to master the activity life cycle.

My question is how does the Lunar Lander stop the thread? And why is mine not stopping with the same code and running at the onSurfaceCreated method. Obviously I am missing something. As far as I know in the Lunar example the only thing that is called on the thread on a destroy is `thread.join()`.

Edit 3: Here is the [Lunar Lander Example Code](https://gitorious.org/replicant/development/source/3eda8fc3859c243df4a1f892a11e2da84b49cb94:samples/LunarLander/src/com/example/android) if needed.

So these are the three override methods in my surfaceview...

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated");

    // start the bluetooth service
    thread.startBluetoothService();

    // start the game
    //if (this.getState() == Thread.State.NEW) {
        Log.d(TAG, "thread start");
        // start running the thread
        this.start();

    //}

    Log.d(TAG, "running to true");
    // release the thread lock
    setRunning(true);
}

// surfaceChanged is called at least once after surfaceCreated
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged");

    // reset the surface size
    thread.setSurfaceSize(width, height);
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed");

    // make sure to shut down the thread cleanly
    boolean retry = true;

    // stop the running thread
    thread.setRunning(false);

    // continuously try to shut down the thread
    while (retry){
            try{
                // blocks calling thread until termination
                thread.join();

                // stop the bluetooth service
                //thread.stopBluetoothService();

                retry = false;
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                //try to shut it down again
            }
    }
}
```

I am really pretty lost with all of this. Any help would be very appreciated, thanks!

Edit:

So I did a little more testing. When the user hits home(which exits the app completely) onPause, then onSurfaceDestroy like I said before. Then when it restarts I get onResume followed by onSurfaceCreated. I think my issue is that it is not calling onCreate when you reenter the app.

Some more questions...
What distinguishes the difference between a onPause and a onDestroy? I think my problem is that since onCreate is not being called I don't have a newly created UI thread which seems like it is still running.

Should the thread be stopped even on a onPause? Because then I am not garenteed to run onCreate which re instantiates the thread. Here is the onCreate code...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wobble);

    // get view and thread
    wobbleView = (WobbleView) findViewById(R.id.wobble);
    wobbleThread = wobbleView.getThread();

    // Get local Bluetooth adapter
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {

        // alert the user of bluetooth failure
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available, using internal devices sensors", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // set the data source to internal sensors - so we'll just use the devices accel
        wobbleThread.setDataSource(WobbleThread.INTERNAL_SENSORS);

    // bluetooth is supported so make sure its enabled and
    }else{

        // make sure bluetooth is enabled on the device
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "starting request to enable bluetooth");
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }

        // all is well with bluetooth - use bluetooth
        Log.d(TAG, "setting bluetooth to bluetooth");
        wobbleThread.setDataSource(WobbleThread.BLUETOOTH);


    }

    // give the LunarView a handle to the TextView used for messages
    wobbleView.setTextView(
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_accel),
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game_msg),
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_score),
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bluetooth_status)
            );


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // we were just launched: set up a new game
        //wobbleThread.setState(wobbleThread.STATE_READY);
    } else {

        //wobbleThread.setRunning(true);
        // we are being restored: resume a previous game
        //wobbleThread.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Edit 2:
Some logcat output

So this is what I get when the thread.start() is called after reopening the app.

```
11-18 22:50:44.104    4868-4868/com.bme.shawn.wobble E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started
            at java.lang.Thread.checkNotStarted(Thread.java:871)
            at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1025)
            at com.bme.shawn.wobble.WobbleThread.startGame(WobbleThread.java:213)
            at com.bme.shawn.wobble.WobbleView.surfaceCreated(WobbleView.java:94)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:580)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:240)
            at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:7903)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1071)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1071)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1071)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1071)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1289)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1050)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5750)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5406)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And if I use the thread.getState check and bypass the error I get this when I close then reopen the app. (logs in basically everything) In this case when the app reopens the thread is not drawing at all. Which is very weird since without the check I get an error saying that the thread is already running.

```
11-18 22:59:13.444    5345-5345/com.bme.shawn.wobble D/WobbleActivity﹕ onPause
11-18 22:59:13.584    5345-5345/com.bme.shawn.wobble D/WobbleView﹕ surfaceDestroyed
11-18 22:59:17.794    5345-5345/com.bme.shawn.wobble D/WobbleActivity﹕ onResume
11-18 22:59:17.804    5345-5345/com.bme.shawn.wobble D/WobbleView﹕ surfaceCreated
11-18 22:59:17.804    5345-5345/com.bme.shawn.wobble D/WobbleThread﹕ running to true
11-18 22:59:17.804    5345-5345/com.bme.shawn.wobble D/WobbleView﹕ surfaceChanged
11-18 22:59:17.804    5345-5345/com.bme.shawn.wobble D/WobbleThread﹕ setting surface sizes
11-18 22:59:17.824    5345-5345/com.bme.shawn.wobble D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3343K, 2% free 6585K/6668K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
11-18 22:59:17.844    5345-5345/com.bme.shawn.wobble E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 44
11-18 22:59:17.854    5345-5345/com.bme.shawn.wobble E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
```

Comment: post your logcat output.

Comment: There you go, thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new instance of the thread in `surfaceCreated()` and start it. And call `thread.join()` in `surfaceDestroyed()`to destroy it.

Comment: How is the Lunar Lander example get away without doing this?

Comment: they are synchronizing surfaceView and setting state explicitly in pause restore and unpause method.

Comment: I am also doing that. I use a setState(mMode) method that is also synchronizing the SurfaceHolder just like they do. I use this method to set it to pause within the onPause method. I unpause the same way on a View tap.

Comment: have you tried creating new instance? is it working ?

Comment: Haven't tried yet. Should I not create the instance of thread in the View constructor?

Comment: No because in the onCreate of the activity it throws a null pointer exception. And if I create an instance of thread in both the constructor and the surfaceCreated then I will have instantiated it twice on a restart.

Comment: you have to create an instance of the thread and start it in on surfacecreated and nowhere else . Not in constructor or oncreate because your surfaceview will be available to display in onsurfacecreated itself and nowhere else. Your thread should start after the surface is available and should stop immediately as soon as surface destroyed try with some easy example first. for more information have a look http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Using-Surface-View-for-Android-1659.php

Comment: Okay, I will try that, I can see how that makes sense. I'm still stuck on the example though. Why does the Lunar Lander example instantiate the thread in the constructor?